# PHP Link to add an underscore, possible?

Tags: php

i'm not using array so i'm a noob to PHP and willing to learn

Here's the code :

```
   if(isset($_POST['cid'],$_POST['gid']))
    {
        $cid = $_POST['cid'];
        $gid = $_POST['gid'];
        $new_link = "www.something.com/ref=".$cid.$gid;
    }
}
```

I want the url to be something like this :

www.something.com/$cid_$gid

just to add an underscore between the cid and gid.

Comment: what your result getting?

Comment: @user3517652 , www.something.com/cidgid. it just stacks together making it look ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$new_link = "www.something.com/ref=".$cid.$gid;
```

with

```
$new_link = "www.something.com/ref=".$cid."_".$gid;
```

Comment: this works perfectly i'll tick the correct answer in 10 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways. My favourite would be [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/function.sprintf.php) which has been a part of PHP since at least version 4.

```
$new_link = sprintf('www.something.com/%s_%s',
    urlencode($cid), urlencode($gid));
```

Comment: sprintf is a good way i really enjoyed it because its advance :)

Comment: Just made it more advanced!